# Cleaning survey data in python - how to finding and cleaning common rows in two files?

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, data-science, data-cleaning

I am working on a survey data analysing project which consist 2 Excel files- in file **pre-survey**, it contains 800+ response records; while in **post-survey** file it contains 500ish responses. Both of them have (at least) one common column SID (Student ID). Something **Y** happened in between, and I am interested analysing the effectiveness of Y, and in what degrade Y impacts on different categories of people.

What adds more complexity is that in each Excel file, it contains multiple tabs. Different interviewers interviewed several interviewees and documented in each tabs for different sections of survey. Columns may or may not be the same for different tabs, so it would be hard to be complied in one file. (Or does it actually make sense to combine them in one with lots of null values?)

I am trying to find the students who did both pre- and post- surveys. How can I do it across sheets and files using python/pandas/other packages?

Bonus if you could also suggest the approach to solve the problem.

Comment: You mention python and pandas in the tags, but only talk about Excelfiles. Do you want to solve this in pandas? Additionally: where _exactly_ are you stuck? Show some sample data, expected output, what you did to solve the problem and why that didn't solve your problem

Comment: Since it's lots of data to do check across sheets and files for the same student who did both surveys manually, I am hoping to find a easier way to clean the data with Python/Pandas or other packages. For the current goal, I'd like to find all the rows in both files with same student id (SID) and drop the rest.

Comment: I am stuck as I (technically) don't know how to (in Python or other languages): 1. combine all the sheets from same file into one compiled one; 2. how to compare between two files; 3. drop the rest of un-interested rows.

Comment: Pre-survey schema: SID;Firstlanguage; International; Gender; Program; pre-score1 ... pre-score99;

Comment: Post-survey schema: SID; Firstlanguage; International; Gender; Program; post-score1 ... post-score99;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm understanding this correctly, your data is currently formatted like this

survey1.xlsx
Sheet 1 (interviewer a)

```
STU-ID QUESTION 1 RESPONSE 1 QUESTION 2 RESPONSE 2
00001  tutoring?  True       lunch a?   False
```

survey1.xlsx
Sheet 2 (interviewer b)

```
STU-ID QUESTION 1 RESPONSE 1 QUESTION 2 RESPONSE 2
00004  tutoring?  True        lunch a?  TRUE
```

survey2.xlsx
Sheet 1

```
STU-ID QUESTION 1    RESPONSE 1 Tutorer GPA
00001  improvement?  True       Jim     3.5
```

survey2.xlsx
Sheet 2 (interviewer b)

```
STU-ID QUESTION 1    RESPONSE 1 Tutorer  GPA
00004  improvement?  yes        Sally    2.8
```

if that's the case, and without knowing the data well, I would combine the tabs so that the pre-survey has the unique student ID (i'm not sure if the same student was interviewed by multiple surveyors) (if they were, you may need to do a group by, but that sounds messy)

Then I would do the same for the post survey response. Then join them into a single dataframe. From the df create a new DF with only the responses you care about (this could get rid of some na answers).

do a df.describe, and a df.dtypes

transform the data so that answers such as "yes/no" become booleans, or atleast so they're all the same format, and the same for numerical responses (int64 or float64)

Finally, I would dropna, so that the df follows your guidelines of containing responses from the first survey, and the second survey.

side note: with only 800 responses, it may be easier to do this just in excel, if you aren't comfortable with python, it would take you several hours to accomplish this, when in excel, it could take you 20 minutes.

If your goal is to learn python, then go for it

Python

```
import pandas as pd

df_s1s1 = pd.read_excel('survey1.xlsx', na_values="Missing", sheet_names='sheet 1', usecols=cols)
df.head()
df_s1s2 = pd.read_excel('survey1.xlsx', na_values="Missing", sheet_names='sheet 2', usecols=cols)
df_s1s2.head()
```

and then the same for the second survey file

```
df_s2s1 = pd.read_excel('survey2.xlsx', na_values="Missing", sheet_names='sheet 1', usecols=cols)
df.head()
df_s2s2 = pd.read_excel('survey2.xlsx', na_values="Missing", sheet_names='sheet 2', usecols=cols)
df_s1s2.head()
```

to add the different sheets to the same dataframe as rows you would use something like this

```
df_survey_1 = pd.concat([df_s1s1, df_s1s2])
df_survey_1.head()
```

then the same for the second survey

```
df_survey_2 = pd.concat([df_s2s1, df_s2s2])
df_survey_2.head()
```

and then to create the larger dataframe with all of the columns you would use something like this

```
master_df = pd.merge(df_survey_1, df_survey2, left_on='STU_ID', right_on='STU_ID')
```

Drop NA

```
master_df = master_df.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
```

hope this helps

Comment: the basic understanding is right. I understand until here, "Then join them into a single dataframe. " The columns are different. How do you join them into a single dataframe and drop the na answers? I'd like to drop the rows (students who did pre- but not post-, or vise versa) instead of columns.

Comment: compare whether student eg. 15, 256, 578, 777 across tabs1,2,3,4 of excel1 exists in tabs1,2,4,6 of excel2 is a pain using excel. I am hoping there are tricks to do it in Python in 20 mins instead of 2hrs in Excel. And I do want to learn Python.

Comment: i updated it with some more information on how to combine sheets, and the merge them together